# Why can't I stay connected to my Linux bluetooth serial port?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I have a USB bluetooth dongle on a Linux 3.12.5 ARM system.  I have been able to make it pairable via:

```
bluetooth-agent 0000 &
```

And then pairing via from my phone.  Then, I create a serial port on the device via:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/rfcomm0 c 216 0
sudo sdptool add --channel=22 SP
sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm 22
```

Then, from my phone, I use BlueTerm to attempt to connect to the serial port.  However, it loses connection immediately.  On the Linux side, the following appears in the terminal:

```
Waiting for connection on channel 22
Authorizing request for /org/bluez/317/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_00_46
```

It doesn't seem to be kicking the phone off the connection, so what's happening?